# lucene phrase query doesn't get results

Tags: c#, lucene

When I run this code does not return any results
Where is the error I'm doing

```
Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo("LuceneIndex"));
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);
var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
Document doc = new Document();            
string path = "beslikelimecogul.txt";
string title = "contents";
doc.Add(new Field("path", path, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("title", title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
writer.Optimize();
writer.Commit();
writer.Close();
Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directory1 = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo("LuceneIndex"));
var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory1);
PhraseQuery query = new PhraseQuery();
query.Add(new Term("contents", "sehid"), 0);
query.Add(new Term("contents", "dusen"), 1);
query.Add(new Term("contents", "gormezden"), 3);
query.Add(new Term("contents", "gelenlerin"), 4);
// display search results
List<string> results = new List<string>();
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(query, 10);
foreach (ScoreDoc scoreDoc in topDocs.ScoreDocs)
{
    Document doc1 = searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc);
    results.Add(doc1.Get("contents").Split(' ')[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you expect Lucene to read the file named `beslikelimecogul.txt`. Don't - you must do this yourself and feed Lucene with the file contents.

Also, you create two fields (`path` and `title`) but you query against `contents`.

Also, there's no need to reopen the same directory, just reuse `directory` instead of creating `directory1`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I'm new in lucene.ı add (term,0),(term,1),(term,3),(term,4) to query. my aim is to find  (term,2) in beşlikelime.txt file. What is the code to be written for this problem?

Comment: I recommend you taking a book or tutorial about Lucene and playing with examples which work. Then, modifying the example to fit your case shouldn't be hard. Sorry, but StackOverflow isn't for writing code for somebody else, SO is about for helping how to write code.